# Photos App & faces sync

Tags: icloud, photos

I am using the new Photos App (Yosemite). Everything is synchronised (iCloud) but the faces.

Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Smart folders — including Faces — on the Mac are (for now) local only. Not only will Faces not sync with iPads or iPhones, they won't sync with other Macs either.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?