# How can a new iPhone know the names of people in my photos?

Tags: iphone, photos, data-synchronization, privacy, photos.app

I recently got a new iPhone. As a part of setting it up I synced my photos from my PC to the new iPhone (as I did with the old device). After that, I waited for the phone to run it's face recognition. What surprised me was that some people got named correctly by the new phone (I provided the names to the old phone). I thought face recognition only runs locally. Both phones have iCloud Photos, My Photo Stream and Shared Albums disabled (the new phone had it enabled by default, but I switched it off in advance of syncing the photos).

Edit: The old phone was the first iPhone SE, the new one's the second generation. Both are running the newest iOS versions.

I was under the impression face recognition feature respect the users (and more important the users friends) privacy and is not crowd sourced and only exists on my device.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name data comes down from [iCloud document and key-value-store sync](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/252697/5472). Even if you don’t use iCloud to store photos, metadata about photos does sync by default. This is similar how to small settings sync between devices. Apple could handle it like screen time where you explicitly opt in or out of this per device, but as of Big Sur and iOS 14 there is no granular opt in or out for this.

Apple doesn’t generate the names, you do on your phone or the iPad / web / macOS version of photos app and then Apple remembers it in your encrypted data store. The “identities” are all machine generated and one “person” can match several machine “matches” in practice.

Until you tell your device to forget that name or that face, that label is attached to the “identity” in the synced data store attached to your iCloud storage bucket.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. I knew that the names must be provieded by me, but I thought that the information is stored locally. Nice to know that faces are stored in iCloud independent of my iCloud settings. This makes it less creepy, but less trustworthy too. Especially since it's not communicated.

Comment: I am not convinced by this answer since it is not consistent with what I am seeing. I have one picture of my 8 year old daughter from a school field trip and most of  the kids have been tagged. Only explanation is that there is some kind of information sharing in iCloud. Guess many parents have their kids tagged which propagates across users. I have a 100 photos of my mother but she is not recognized- likely because she isn’t tagged in any other person’s iPhone that syncs up to iCloud. Super creepy stuff

Comment: There may be very new mechanics at play now with iOS 17 and related OS due to the identity card features. Anyone with details - please edit this if you have updates before I can test / understand and see if there's any need to update. Thanks for the excellent comment @SAS2Python

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Apple's cloud solution to sync photos. So there is no surprise that new iPhone got info from the iCloud about your friends. Relax, we are all indexed ;)

Comment: I did *not* use iCloud to sync my photos. Could it be that the new device got the information previously synced to iCloud without any of  iCloud Photos, My Photo Stream and Shared Albums enabled?